# How do i add items to a list property using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having difficulties understanding how to add items to my list while using Entity Framework.
My database has been created and the tables are there, but the table for my options stays empty when i try to add options through my seed method.

How do i add my options correctly so that they appear in my database and are linked to the correct vehicle?

I have 2 models:

**Vehicle**

```
public class VehicleModels
    {

        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Naam { get; set; }
        public virtual string Merk { get; set; }
        public virtual string Brandstof { get; set; }
        public virtual string Kleur { get; set; }
        public virtual string TypeVanMerk { get; set; }
        public virtual string TypeVanTransmissie { get; set; }
        public virtual int Kilometerstand { get; set; }
        public virtual int Bouwjaar { get; set; }
        public virtual int AantalDeuren { get; set; }
        public List<Optie> Options { get; set; }

        public VehicleModels()
        {
            Options = new List<Optie>();
        }

        public void AddOption(Optie optie) {
            if (!Options.Equals(null))
            {
                Options.Add(optie);
            }  
        }


    }
```

And **Option**

```
public class Optie
    {
        public virtual int OptieId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Naam { get; set; }

        public Optie(string naam)
        {
            Naam = naam;
        }
    }
```

And this is my Seed/Initializer

```
public class VehicleDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<VehicleDB>
    {

        protected override void Seed(VehicleDB context)
        {
            context.VehicleModels.Add(new VehicleModels
            {
                Naam = "Auto 1",
                Merk = "Audi",
                Brandstof = "Benzine",
                Kleur = "Rood",
                TypeVanMerk = "A6",
                TypeVanTransmissie = "Manueel",
                Kilometerstand = 60000,
                Bouwjaar = 2002,
                AantalDeuren = 5
            });
            context.VehicleModels.Add(new VehicleModels
            {
                Naam = "Auto 2",
                Merk = "BMW",
                Brandstof = "Diesel",
                Kleur = "Silver",
                TypeVanMerk = "6",
                TypeVanTransmissie = "Manueel",
                Kilometerstand = 25000,
                Bouwjaar = 2012,
                AantalDeuren = 3
            });

            VehicleModels vehicle = new VehicleModels();
            vehicle.Naam = "Auto 3";
            vehicle.Merk = "Volvo";
            vehicle.Brandstof = "Diesel";
            vehicle.Kleur = "Silver";
            vehicle.TypeVanMerk = "6";
            vehicle.TypeVanTransmissie = "Manueel";
            vehicle.Kilometerstand = 25000;
            vehicle.Bouwjaar = 2012;
            vehicle.AantalDeuren = 3;


            vehicle.Options.Add(new Optie("Airco"));
            vehicle.Options.Add(new Optie("Trekhaak"));
            vehicle.Options.Add(new Optie("Airbags"));

            context.VehicleModels.Add(vehicle);

            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
```

Global.aspx.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new VehicleDbInitializer());

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
```

Comment: share your  Global.aspx code please ?

Comment: are you sure your seed method calling? do you have any idea about migration? then apply please . what is happening?

Comment: Seed is running because the vehicle are added, just not the options, no migration done yet, i did delete the whole database by hand a few times and recreated it to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to call `context.SaveChanges()` at the end of your Seed method maybe?

Comment: Appreciate the effort but nope, this has no effect on the creation of the database in the Seed method. This also is not mentioned in any of the documentation that i have been using for this project.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add following:

```
private List<Optie> tempList= new List<Optie>();    
public List<Optie> Options 
{
    get
    {
         return tempList;
    }
}
```

and remove following:

```
public VehicleModels()
{
    Options = new List<Optie>();
}

public void AddOption(Optie optie) {
    if (!Options.Equals(null))
    {
        Options.Add(optie);
    }  
}
```